# Display a user form by categories of "questions" in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Using Symfony, I'm building a budgeting app which allows each user to access a table of their expenses, and edit it.

So in short, it displays a `<form>` using Symfony formTypes inside the cells of a `<table>` where each line represents a particular kind of expense.

[image: The form]

So I have a user table/entity and a expenseLine table/entity, linked by a OneToOne relation, and that allows me to call up all of a user's expense lines and edit it.

It works fine so far, but each kind of expense has a category (stored in an other table with a OneToMany relation), and I would like to display the budget lines by categories.

So far, I haven't been able to work up the logic of how to do that. I managed to display the category of each user's expense, but not display the user's expenses by category (without displaying those of the other users).

And I wonder how I should imbricate the formTypes so that I don't only display it but allow for modifications with the same display.

Could anyone point me toward the right direction?

EDIT:

The formType:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\LineCategory;
use App\Form\BudgetLineType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class MakeUserTableType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('BudgetTable', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => BudgetLineType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false]]);
        
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the FormType look? You probably have a field of type `Entity` in there? In that field you can add options to change the query that is being used to fetch all expenses by limiting them to a user, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

Comment: I put the formTypecode at the end of my post ! Right now, i'm basing it on the User entity and then calling up the budgetLineType inside it to edit every expense linked to the user.

If I understand what you say, and the doc you referenced, I should make a form about the categories, and add option inside it so that it would fetch, for each category, the expense of only one user ? So basically go about it the other way than what i'm doing ?